# VBA truncate value

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to truncate some values because round functions don't fit my issue since I want to compare the values I'm dealing with with some others values but I don't if they were rounded up or down so I get errors.

Anyway, I've tried many things but still don't get what I want... The must would be something like `=TRUNC` but it is not available in VBA...

My last try which almost gave what I wanted is :

```
.Cells(iLine, iCol) = Int(.Cells(iLine, iCol).Value * 1000) / 1000
```

But the problem is that sometimes when I have a "`-1`" it gives "`-1.001`" so that messes things up... I don't really know why it does that since I put a msgbox after the `* 1000` (so before the `/ 1000`) and the result is -1000. So the problem comes from the division.

--> So if anyone knows a better solution to truncate or if you know why `1000/1000` gives me `-1.001` thank you in advance !

---

Another solution was :

```
Range(.Cells(iLine, iCol), .Cells(iLine, iCol)).Select 
Selection.NumberFormat = "0.000"
Range(.Cells(iLine, iCol), .Cells(iLine, iCol)) = Range(.Cells(iLine, iCol), .Cells(iLine, iCol)).Text * 1
```

But this is not what I'm looking because of two things :

1. It forces my cell format to 0.000 which isn't confortable/aesthetic to read when you have -1.000
2. It is not possible to do that with simple values only with ranges (I'm not about this one though)

---

**EDIT :** after some several test on my line `.Cells(iLine, iCol) = Int(.Cells(iLine, iCol) * 1000) / 1000` it appears that the problem comes from the `Int()` function. Because `-1*1000 = -1000` but `int(-1000) = -1001`. Anyone knows why this happens ?

Even when I increase the precision of this cell by let's say -1.000000 I get the same problem, it's only when I put Int() on it that the extra 1 apprears

Comment: `Int(.Cells(iLine, iCol) * 1000) / 1000` gives me `1` if `.Cells(iLine, iCol).Value` is `-1`. As blind shots, check if you have any funny format. Or try `.Value2` instead of `.Value`

Comment: @jack - See the edit to my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51782530/8112776) re: [floating point number precision](https://support.office.com/article/set-rounding-precision-e5d707e3-07a8-4df2-810c-218c531eb06a)

Comment: Use [Fix instead of Int](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/int-fix-functions) returns the next value under or equal if the number is negative. `Int(-1000.0000001) = -1001` while `Fix(-1000.0000001) = -1000`.

Comment: As to your question can someone explain why "1000/1000 gives me -1.001"? Please read [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html). Especially the section "Rounding error".

Comment: @VincentG That just moves the problem: `Fix(-999.999999999999) = -999`. It's a floating point math problem, using either `Int` or `Fix` to display a set amount of decimals will result the last decimal to be inaccurate.

Comment: @VincentG I've tried fix and gave to many errors...

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth, if the user want to truncate, I explain how to truncate. Displaying floating point value is almost always inaccurate.

Comment: @Miqi180 yes that's what I thought in the first place that it was -1.0009999 but the thing is I've increased my decimal to the orignal value and it was -1.0000000 (didn't go further)

Comment: I added more notes to my answer...  are these variables declared? ...as an integer or a floating point type?

Comment: `but int(-1000) = -1001` <- that is not true.

Comment: @JackA I'm not sure what `cell()` data type you're referring to in the comment on my answer, but regardless, if you use an Integer data type for all related variables in VBA then you will never get anything except integer (whole) numbers (without decimal places).  I suspect you're not declaring your variables...?

Comment: @JackA -  Perhaps "truncate" is word that's confusing people in your question.  If ***rounding***, not truncating, is the goal, you can use `Round`.  For example `Round(-1.0009999,0)` returns `-1` and `Round(-999.999999999999,0)` returns `1000`.

Comment: @ashleedawg no I want to truncate not round.. But I've found some solution (I posted it as an answer)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I wanted to truncate my value and got a wrong number. To test if it was some rounding problem I tried to round to 10-6 before truncating to 10-3 and that worked :

```
.Cells(iLine, iCol) = Round(.Cells(iLine, iCol), 6)
.Cells(iLine, iCol) = Int(.Cells(iLine, iCol).Value * 1000) / 1000
```

I don't feel like this tells us why `int(-1000.000000)` gives `-1001.000000` but hey, that works !

### Thank you everyone

**EDIT :** I've just realized that Int() actually rounds because microsoft's doc says that `INT(-4.5) = -5` So I guess my -1 was actually `-1.0000[...]00001`...

Comment: The thing is, `int(-1000.000000)` does ***not*** return `-1001` on a normal system, with regular setup. I just triple-checked. There is something else going on with your workbook.  I'd be curious what you et if you try in a new workbook.

Comment: @ashleedawg Yes I don't feel really good about this either... But I think it's because it a negative value (I've edited my answer, I forgot the `-`)

Comment: i added an image to my answer showing that it's **not** normal behaviour - you must have something else setup weird, or perhaps the cell format is affecting it.

Comment: @JackA `int(-1000)` does **not** produce the result -1001 in the Immediate window. Similarly, `Int(-1.00000000000000001)` gives you -1. However, if your problem does not stem from a rounding error when Excel converts from an integer to a floating-point number, cf. the article I linked to, I would suggest that you check whether the value of the cell is in fact -1. Try selecting the cell and printing the value to the immediate window with `Debug.Print ActiveCell` and check if the value is something like -1,0000000000001.

Comment: @ashleedawg Yes I thought about that too so I made sure that my cell format was set to "standard"

Answer (score 1):

One way to truncate a decimal (ie., floating-point) number to be an integer (eg. no decimal places) is to use the `INT` function.

```
MsgBox Int(1.234)
```

*or*

```
MsgBox Int(1.789)
```

...both return `1`.

Note that this function works both in VBA and in worksheet formulas.

---

### Floating Point Rounding Errors

> You can frequently prevent floating point rounding errors from affecting your work by setting the Precision as displayed option before you apply a number format to your data. This option forces the value of each number in the worksheet to be at the precision that is displayed on the worksheet.
>
> **Note:** Using the **Precision as displayed** option can have cumulative calculation effects that can make your data increasingly inaccurate over time. Use this option only if you are certain that the displayed precision will maintain the accuracy of your data.

More on this from the [source](https://support.office.com/article/set-rounding-precision-e5d707e3-07a8-4df2-810c-218c531eb06a) and [here](https://support.microsoft.com/help/214118/how-to-correct-rounding-errors-in-floating-point-arithmetic).

---

### *Edit:* Rounding issues when referring to worksheet directly

I can't reproduce your issue here, but it could depend on other factors such as cell format and Excel's settings.

Likely the easiest/best way to ensure you don't have this problem is to put the number into an integer variable before doing any calculations.

So instead of:

```
Range("A2") = Int( Range("A1") / 1000 ) * 1000
```

use:

```
Dim myInt as Integer, myInt2 as Integer  'don't 'Dim' variables within a loop

myInt = Range("A1")
myInt2 = Int( myInt / 1000 ) * 1000
Range("A2") = myInt2
```

---

### More Information:

- Office Support : [**`INT` Function** (Excel Worksheet)](https://support.office.com/article/int-function-a6c4af9e-356d-4369-ab6a-cb1fd9d343ef)
- MSDN : [**`Int`, `Fix` Functions** (VBA)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/int-fix-functions)
- Office Support : [**Set rounding precision**](https://support.office.com/article/set-rounding-precision-e5d707e3-07a8-4df2-810c-218c531eb06a)
- Office Support : [**How to correct rounding errors in floating-point arithmetic**](https://support.microsoft.com/help/214118/how-to-correct-rounding-errors-in-floating-point-arithmetic)

---

## *Another Edit:*

I'm glad you think you found a solution but my concern is that what you're describing is not normal behaviour.  Proof:

[image: img]

...and so, while your workaround may give you the right answer in this case, there may be other calculations being affected by this that are not so obvious.

There are a number of settings that could affect this.  I'd suggest trying again with a new, blank workbook, ideally after rebooting.

Comment: @JackA then I misunderstand. What do you want to have returned from, say, `1.0001`? Are are you only wondering "why"?

Comment: Thank you for the sources I'll check that. To answer, I have a x value that I multiply by 1000 then use int() on that and then redivide it by 1000. But if x = -1 in that particular case it gives me -1.001 instead of -1. Also look at my EDIT on my original post

Comment: @JackA - what data type is `x`? It will likely make a difference whether you're using, for example, `Integer` or `Single`. Or, if you're not declaring them at all then they are probably `Variant`.

Comment: The data type of x is actually a `cell()`

Comment: That is not a built-in data type. Is it custom?

Comment: I know... But I'm not using any variable for this calculation. Only the `cell().Value`

Comment: in that case, I would suggest that instead of  referring to the cell directly, you put it into an integer variable and do your math with that.  I will edit my answer with an example

Comment: @Jack - you didn't understand the question when being asked the datatype of the cell's value, here. We all know you're pulling data from a cell - `cell()` is not a datatype. If the cell contained something like `100,000` it can only go into `String` because of the comma, while `100000` would be a `Long`, because it is an `Integer`, but higher than the `Integer` limit (32,767). So the length of the number & if it has a decimal determines the type. See: https://www.educba.com/vba-data-types/ and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/data-type-summary

Answer (score 1):

you could use `Trunc()` function:

```
.Cells(iLine, iCol).Formula="=Trunc(" & .Cells(iLine, iCol).Value & ",3)"
.Cells(iLine, iCol).Value = .Cells(iLine, iCol).Value
```

Comment: Actually, afterwards I want to use what I'm doing on variable so not an option here..

Comment: I don't get you: my code is acting on `.Cells(iLine, iCol)` in the same way as yours. so what must you do _"on variable"_?

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear... In my example I'm working on a cell. But later in my code I'm going to compare what I've done in my cells with others values that I'm calculating in `double var`. So I can't work with `.Formula`. I hope I was easier to understand this time...

Comment: the last line (namely `.Cells(iLine, iCol).Value = .Cells(iLine, iCol).Value`) gets rid of the formula and leaves you with only its result

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you would multiply by 1000, turn it to `Int`, then divide by 1000... you would just go back to what you had, except you converted it to an Integer in between, which could round it just on its own without the multiplying and dividing, but that's obviously not what you want...

Much simpler, just put your value into a `Double`:

```
Dim ourNumber As Double
ourNumber = 3.14159265457279
```

Then make a string and manipulate it that way. Assign your number to a string variable you create by converting it to string, and then you can manipulate it as a string:

```
Dim myDoubleStr As String
myDoubleStr = CStr(ourNumber)
myDoubleStr = Left(myDoubleStr, 4) ' equals 3.14
```

Then you can put it back to double for calculations or whatever you want:

```
ourNumber = CDbl(myDoubleStr)
```

So, to relate this back to your Excel scenario:

```
' Assuming we are passing in iLine and iCol...
Dim ourNumber As Double
ourNumber = worksheet.Range(iLine & ":" & iCol).Value

Dim myDoubleStr As String
myDoubleStr = CStr(ourNumber)
myDoubleStr = Left(myDoubleStr, 4)

worksheet.Range(iLine & ":" & "iCol").Value = CDbl(myDoubleStr)
```